# Firestore (Firebase) How to count total active/online users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to create an app with some features below:

- No need to signup or login to use the app
- Everyday, my admin will upload a 10 mins long (or less) audio file to backend and setup the time when the audio will be available for all users. E.g: 10am
- 5 mins before the setup time (9.55am), the app will start to count total number of users who are opening the app and waiting for to play the audio file.
- **The number of active/online users will be real time**.

What I tried:

- Every time user opens the audio screen, the app will use FirebaseAuth to login as anonymous. When user leaves this screen, using FirebaseAuth to logout. But this approach doesn't work since when user logs out, the anonymous user is still there on the Users table

My questions:

1. With those features, can I use firebase/firestore to implement?
2. What is the best approach to count total active users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `FirebaseAuth` to write a value into the database, if the auth returns that someone is using the app, write a reference and keep adding users on it.

I mean, if there is an user online, `FirebaseAuth` will write to a reference called `usersonline` a value of 1 , if another user joins it's going to be `usersonline + 1` and so on, and then you can attach an `onChildEventListener` and update in realtime the users online with `onChildChanged`, so, each time that child changes (incrementing depending the users) it will be showing the users online.

To decrement the users online, after they logout and an `AuthListener` is no longer seeing the logged in user, you can decrement just by 1 each time an user logs out, so, if an user logs out, the AuthListener will fire and you can modify your child with `usersonline - 1` each time this happens.

For example, Firebase manages to write data to the database when an user loses their connection.

```
// Write a string when this client loses connection
presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I disconnected!");
```

You can check it in the offline capabilities:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities

So instead of writing (" i disconnected!") what you want to achieve is to decrement the usersonline ref by 1 , so you will be adding people and removing them from that child like realtime online users.

This snippet from that doc is really good to achieve what you are looking for

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
    if (connected) {
      System.out.println("connected"); // tell your usersonline ref to increment by 1
    } else {
      System.out.println("not connected"); //then if the user is not longer connected just decrement your usersonline by 1
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
  }
});
```

In terms of simultaneous connections, this is for Firebase realtime database:

> The Spark plan limit is 100 and cannot be raised. The Flame and Blaze
>   plans have a limit of 100,000 simultaneous connections per database.
>   If you need more than 100,000 simultaneous connections, contact
>   Firebase support.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas for Firestore, 100k is the limit for simultaneous connections at the moment, **this is just for the beta period**.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Is this firebase database or firestore? As I know with real time database, the limitation is Simultaneous connections (100)

Comment: Can we use Firestore to avoid the plan limit?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas   for firestore, 100k is the limit , this is just for the beta period

Comment: well first of all what you should do to maintain a secure app is make an array of users online inside a doc, the array will have the uid of each user connected, and you should use a firestore function to update another field value containing the size of the array, the function will use an onDocumentChangeListener so the field containing the number of online users shouldn't be inside the document, the problem with this method and yours is that the users can still be online but not necessarly active.