# Flutter - Is it possible to show the number of users online?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to show how many people are using my mobile application instantly in my application. For example: "342 people are currently using the application." or "342 people are online right now." I could not find a solution for this.

I store users data with Firebase. So what I want to do is possible by extracting data from the firebase?

Comment: maybe can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50558974/firestore-firebase-how-to-count-total-active-online-users

Comment: https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802

Comment: I've seen this, but in this example it finds the number of online users on the web. Could this structure be valid in the mobile application? So how can I check this when they exit my app?

Answer (score 0):

You're simplest and most cost effective way, is to create a document, put in a collection for example called `.collection(general)`, when a user logsIn, add `1` to that value, when they logout, subtract 1, and put this in a stream builder.

After success login, run the following function

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('general')
        .doc('onlineCount)
        .update({'membersOnline': FieldValue.increment(1)})//this will increase the number by 1.
    );
```

On logout, substract 1.

Comment: This approach just to know how many users have login on app not, online users, suppose a user is authenticated but he quit the app, he will be counted as an online user but it is the opposite :p

Answer (score 0):

this is very easy to handle this logic just save the status when users open your app for eg: on homepage and when they kill your app just update that collection to that particular is offline and at the and do query

```
     where(user:online)
```

and check the number of users you got and simply show that number.

I hope you got this logic.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party. But I would personally recommend making use of the App Lifecycle. Meaning:
**detached:** The application is still hosted on a flutter engine but is detached from any host views.
**inactive:** The application is in an inactive state and is not receiving user input. For example during a phone call.
**paused:** The application is not currently visible to the user and running in the background. This is when you press the Home button.
**resumed:** The application is visible and responding to user input. In this state, the application is in the foreground.

So you will have to create a `StatefulWidget` and `WidgetsBindingObserver`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LifeCycleManager extends StatefulWidget {
  LifeCycleManager({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  _LifeCycleManagerState createState() => _LifeCycleManagerState();
}

class _LifeCycleManagerState extends State<LifeCycleManager> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    print('AppLifecycleState: $state');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.child;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And then just check the states as follows:

```
AppLifecycleState _appLifecycleState;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    setState(() {
      _appLifecycleState = state;
    });
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      print('AppLifecycleState state: Paused audio playback');
//update user file eg. online_status: offline
    }
    if(state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      print('AppLifecycleState state: Resumed audio playback');
//update user file eg. online_status: online
    }
    print('AppLifecycleState state:  $state');
  }
```